# Flutter Plugin issue in IntelliJ IDEA 17.2

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, flutter

I am trying to add plugin for flutter as recommended by flutter in their site and i am facing two different issues in it

1. I couldn't find plugin named Flutter in their plugin directory even though they have in their site 
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
2. if I download the plugin via the sit and install it the plugin referring from disk in IntelliJ, it say it is incompatible.

Anyone facing same kind of issue or anyone found a workaround for this.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 17.2

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Flutter plugin doesn't yet support EAP versions of IntelliJ.

There is an open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/400

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gunter. Appreciate your feedback. Finally after creating a second flutter app and loading it in IntellJ , if automatically recognized flutter plugin available to be download and it installs the plugin after i accept the download and installation which followed by a restart for it get activated.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Android Studio: [Documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio)

1. Open preferences (Android Studio > Check for Updates)
2. If dart or flutter are listed, update them.